# How to fake the request to Google Form with Java Script?

Tags: javascript, google-forms

I want to complete the form of Google like [this](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd4j0ETux_W6x7nfmE_2EkyJr869C0F0d_QuN5jyNS5xRQ78g/viewform?fbzx=-4719014590155394000) with out fill in that form. So I use java script to send the request to that link but the method "post" didn't working.Someone please help me.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it not work because different domain, you need to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) by installing extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) without it you can only send the form but not see the how response. another method without installing extension is, visit form page then run javascript snippet in chrome console.

and the right form Post URL is

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/<Form_ID>/formResponse
```